# How to let UriBuilder build an URI with decoded hash character?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I try to generate following uri

//host:port/name/#/name/name

with jersey URI Builder. The Problem is that the uri builder decode the hash character.

Does anyone how to build the given URI?

Thats what I have:

```
final URI build = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path("..").path("#").path("/clients/asd/").build();
```

Comment: you could try `.path(URLEncoder.encode("#"))`

Comment: @Alden 1. `URLEncoder.encode()` doesn't work for URIs; 2. OP actually wants a URI fragment, not to escape the hash sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is not a valid character in a URI path; `#` and what follows it is actually a URI *fragment*.

What you need to do is therefore:

```
final URI build = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path("..")
    .fragment("/clients/asd/").build();
```

(note: I don't use Jersey, actually; I looked up the javadoc [here](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html), as I suppose this is the same)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is what worked:

```
final URI build = UriBuilder.fromUri("{arg1}").fragment("{arg2}").buildFromEncoded("../","/clients/asd/");
```

Using `.path("..").fragment("/clients/asd/").build()` would generate

> ..#%2Fclients%2Fasd